# Pandas Python splitting a row , using it to count how many times it appears and replacing the results

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, split, count

Suppose a data frame with 3 columns looks like this:

```html
.    Values  Objects     Legs

0     1        568        25
1     5        387        56
2     0        526        52
3     3        982        89
4     0        098        09
5     8        697        89
6     0        647        01
```

I want to create code that says if `row(Values) == 0`, `split corresponding row(objects).str[2]` and use the split number to count how many times it appears in `Legs` column and then create a dataframe with the results. Rows that are not zero should be left as they are. I have the following code but returns error `Str has no str attribute`

```js
#
import panda as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Hello world')

#Making index loop for every 'Values' row
for index in df.index:

   #checking for zero 
   if df.loc[index,'Values'] == 0.0:
   
   #Splitting the 'Objects' row and counting how many times the split str in the 'Legs' Column when true
   df.loc[df.Legs == df.loc[0,'Objects'].astype(str).str[2], 'Legs'].count()
```

> Expected output

```js
.    Values  Objects     Legs   Counts

0     1        568        25      
1     5        387        56
2     0        526        52      1         #Counted 52 in 'Legs'
3     3        982        89
4     0        098        09      1         #Counted 09 in  'Legs' 
5     8        697        89
6     0        647        01      0         #Counted 64 in 'Legs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reformat your columns to contain leading zeros when they are read. You can then fill the `Counts` column as shown here:

```
df['Objects']=df['Objects'].apply('{:0>3}'.format)
df['Legs']=df['Legs'].apply('{:0>2}'.format)
df['Counts']=None
for index in df.index:
    if df.loc[index,'Values'] == 0.0:
        df.loc[index,'Counts']=df.loc[df['Legs'] == df.loc[index,'Objects'][:2], 'Legs'].count()
```

Output:

```
    Values  Objects Legs    Counts
0   1   568 25  None
1   5   387 56  None
2   0   526 52  1
3   3   982 89  None
4   0   098 09  1
5   8   697 89  None
6   0   647 01  0
```

Comment: How do I limit the process only to a certain number of rows?

Comment: `df[:10]` will give you the first ten rows of df.

Comment: `for index in df.[:10]`?

Comment: It will be `for index in df[:10].index`